# Adding new column/field into attribute table in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-online, fields-attributes

Is it possible to add a new column in the attribute table using the ArcGIS Online version or do I have to return to my home computer and do this through QGIS?

A little background to help better understand exactly what I'm doing:
I am working with ArcGIS Online at work and have successfully uploaded my parcel data after using QGIS on my home computer to convert it from the geo database into a shape file. I'm being asked to list each parcel by the property owner. I figured the best way to do this would be to add a field in the attribute table named 'owner' and populate the attributes that way.

Comment: So I realized that by clicking on a parcel within the map document a small box displaying attribute information pops up and has an edit button in the bottom left corner which allows one to change existing data. 

Still unsure on how to add a whole new column to the table

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to provide an update to this question, I know it was awhile back.

So, yes, it is now possible to add a field to an already existing table in ArcGIS Online.

Just open the attribute table, click on Table Options on the right hand-side, and then select Add Field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to add an additional field in ArcGIS online through your web browser.

However, if you have access to ArcMap at work, you can sign into your ArcGIS online account and it will load your map from ArcGIS online. From there you can open up your shapefile and add a new field.

However, I'm not sure if the same functionality exists within QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields on ArcGIS online via your web browser by having high enough clearance. If your organization lists you as "User" under 'My Profile' and 'Role' you cannot add fields but you can edit attribute tables. If your organization lists you as "Publisher" than you can add fields. Adding fields is done through table options by either opening the attribute table in Web Map Viewer and selecting the table options in the corner of the table or by opening the feature layer > 'Data' and under table options there is an option to add fields.